# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

can someone point out what is causing this error? I've been trying to fix it but I failed. I don't understand what is wrong with the 'ID' ... which part exactly that generated this error?

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;

    string str = "SELECT * FROM Student "
        + " WHERE Student ID = '" + StudentID.Text + "' AND "
        + " Password = '" + SPassword.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    conn.Open();
    reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();


    if (reader.Read())
    {

        if (StudentID.Text == "900000000")

            Response.Write("<body onload=\"window.open('Admin.aspx', '_top')\"></body>");

        else

            Response.Write("<body onload=\"window.open('user.aspx', '_top')\"></body>");

    }
    else
        lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Username and/or Password, please re-try!!";

    conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: Explicitly writing code with SQL injection is not a good idea. Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[c%23]%20sql%20injection for correct approach with using parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student.ID ...` (you have a space instead of a dot)

You could omit the `Student` entirely and just use `ID` (like you have for `Password`).

Comment: After I fixed it.. there is a new error that says (Invalid column name 'StudentID') what might be the cause?

Comment: While correct it is not a good suggestion - OP needs to use parametrized queries to construct SQL request.

Comment: What is the name of the ID column you are trying to pull from the DB? - that is what you need in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @John3136 Its name is 'StudentID" .. it's the same in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't know, that's how I'm studying it in college. would you please provide a source that teach what you're suggesting? thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = ...`